# Need to create an activity?

Tags: product

I'm new to Magento, I'm developing a traveller website in which I need some ideas on how to create an activity by the user selects a particular activity and selects the city or the user can also select from date - to date and select the city. And based on the above selection parameters user should be able to view the list of hotels and select lunch/Dinner at that respective hotel.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Thoughts to others, is Magento the best platform to go for this type of solution?   I'm seriously curious what others think.

Comment: If you are using magento 1.9 and lower version you can use some paid extension for Bookings & Reservations functionality